# Язык C, звездочка в спецификаторе формата для строки

Tags: c, scanf

Допустим есть код:

```
#define BUF_SIZE (100)

char buf[BUF_SIZE];
scanf("%99s", buf);
```

Я бы хотел, чтобы константа **BUF_SIZE** использовалась и для задания размера буфера, и для спецификатора формата.

В спецификаторе формата допустима звездочка, и я пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде:

```
scanf("%*s", BUF_SIZE - 1, buf);
```

Но это не работает.

Подскажите, как это можно сделать, чтобы макроконстанта использовалась не только для задания размера буфера, но и для спецификатора чтения.

Конечно, можно использовать **scanf_s()**, но такой вариант негибок.

Comment: А чего Вы хотели добиться? Что делает звездочка в спецификаторе? - она просто говорит, что нужно пропустить этот элемент, а не читать. Вы хотели, в спецификатор вставить нужную длину строки? Тогда это, например, можно сделать через использование еще одной строки, а ее формируете через `sprintf()` уже с использованием Вашего макроса.

Comment: Ну звездочка работает например так: printf("%*.*f", 2, 2, value);

Comment: А почему Вы думаете, что `scanf()` и `printf()` - имеют абсолютно одинаковые спецификаторы? У них звездочка означает разные вещи. Собственно, Вам ниже уже даже пример набросали ;-) .

Comment: Эх, а я-то думал... Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто попробовать создать строку формата отдельно

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SIZE (100)

char format[10];
sprintf(format, "%%%ds", BUF_SIZE - 1);

char buf[BUF_SIZE];
scanf(format, buf);
```

---

UPD. Поправил на пример из комментария.

Comment: Можно проще: `sprintf(format, "%%%ds", BUF_SIZE - 1);`

Comment: @insolor действительно, спасибо